# Regex to get a backreference with an optional part

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

Submission 1052 (topic) was deleted by user *username*

After this string, there could be a colon followed by a reason for the removal. Now, I need a backreference in PHP's preg_replace to replace this the way I want it (in my case, I link the username). I've tried quite a few expressions, but I can't seem to get the results I want. Mostly my expressions results in that the link continues on after the colon (I want the link to stop right before the colon).

The regular expression I'm using now looks like this:

```
<?php preg_replace("/Submission ([0-9]+) (\(.*\)) was deleted by user (.*)(|: .*)/",'<span style="color:red;">Submission <a href="#">$1</a> $2 was deleted by user <a href="#">$3</a>$4</span>',$string) ?>
```

Here, I basically thought that (|: .*) would check for an empty string OR (|) a colon followed by anything (but I think I'm dead wrong).

Comment: Why not split on `":"` first?

Comment: Split? What did you have in mind? preg_split?

Comment: No. Split first. One problem is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** Based upon your comment.

I've put a `?` after the `*` which makes it non-greedy. As it was, it was grabbing everything to the end of the line.

```
...user (.*?)(: .*)?$
```

Explanation:

```
(.*?)   # Match any number of chars as short as possible.
(: .*)? # Match 0 or 1 of : .*.
$       # Match the end of the line.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. The link still extends past the colon. I think it has to do with the groups being right next to each other.

Comment: I've adjusted the regex to make the first `.*` after `user` non-greedy meaning it will match as short a string as possible.